# Gray out a section of an image with CSS

Tags: css, image, filter

I'm trying to grey out a section of an image (two stripes at left and right). Is there a way to do this using just CSS?

I know I can use filters (i.e. `filter: grayscale(100%)`), but I don't want the entire image to be grey.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pure CSS Solution with no extra markup

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gmU9y/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="image-grey" src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-container {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.image-grey {
    display:block;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.image-container:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:50%;
        width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/200/150);
    background-position:top right;
}
```

Comment: I commented when I saw the final effect, but it's not exactly what I need (its just the half). I need to add two gray stripes to the image, not just one. I'm trying different things with this technique, but I couldn't find a way to add another grey stripe to the right side. Maybe what I'm trying to do needs to be done with javascript or something else.

Comment: Now it's officially what I wanted.

Comment: If you want to use `background-size: cover;`, this example won't work. But I [forked the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m04Lnt1a/) so it will also be able to do that!

Answer (score 2):

Put a div over it.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="path/to/file.jpg" />
    <div id="filter">
</div>
<style>
#wrapper {position: relative;}
#filter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 123px;
    left: 123px;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BQ7J3/

Comment: +1 I was just in the process of making a JSFiddle for this (only I used PlaceCage :) http://jsfiddle.net/jM7S6/

Comment: Of course that's not greying out the image as such, it's darkening the colors that are there. http://jsfiddle.net/W4tY6/ . However, it might suffice instead.

Comment: It looks like what I want, but not exactly. The background alpha property doesn't do the trick for me. Cool trick though.

Comment: There really isn't much difference between a filter and a semi-transparent background. If you don't wand darkening, then use #fff or something.

Comment: Wand darkening! Scary!

Answer (score 2):

If you do indeed wish to use the greyscale filter you will need to have two images on top of each other, one with the greyscale filter applied and clipped to the size you wish.

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="image-grey clip" src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
    <img class="image-coloured" src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />  
</div>
```

and

```
.image-coloured {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.image-grey {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.clip {
    clip: rect(0px,60px,150px,0px)
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ys7Mj/3/)

Comment: OP: "Is there a way to do this using just CSS?"

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why you are pointing this out to me?

Comment: Your not using only css. Your requiring another image.

Comment: Any solution is likely going to require some addition markup, just like your proposal did - especially since the OP did not post the context of the image :)